# Can I include under-review content in my PhD Thesis?

Tags: phd, journals, conference, thesis

In the verge of writing up a PhD thesis, is it fine to include the content of the work which is submitted to a conference and is "under review" at the time of writing up. More specifically if the conference has 'double-blind' review process.Or is it advisable to wait till the review decision on publication is out.

Please suggest.

Thanks, KR

Comment: This really depends on the times. If you are writing up at this moment, I'd wait a little bit for acceptance/rejection before adding it, because it could be rejected, and then you would have in your thesis a paper that has been rejected. Rejected papers seem not to exist... PD: I just saw your history (_don't judge me!_) so the basic advice is: do as in the other question (if you can't wait).

Comment: @Trylks I don't understand, doesn't a rejected paper (assuming that the work is correct) simply get resubmitted to another journal?

Comment: @AruRay I think the problem arises if it gets rejected because the work is *not* correct.

Comment: Ask your supervisor.

Comment: @AruRay as gerrit says, the main problem is a rejection because the work is not correct. But even in the best case, *assuming* it's correct, resubmitted and accepted in a different journal, how are you going to edit the journal name in the printed book of your thesis?

Comment: "I think the problem arises if it gets rejected because the work is not correct." …in which case your committee should not approve your thesis! (You know, there was a time when *most* PhD theses did not contain peer-reviewed work…)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am sure this may vary but this is standard procedure for our theses since they are based on papers. A student will typically have about four papers/manuscripts in their thesis ranging from published through all stages of revision in a journal to not yet submitted manuscripts.

You will need to check with your local guidelines what is expected from a thesis to figure out the details but it would seem difficult to demand all published papers unless the period to complete a PhD is open ended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the responses. I will contact my advisor for his suggestion and refer uni guidelines for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but you should clearly label it as "submitted to xyz" to make clear it is not accepted, yet. You should update the status ("accepted for xyz", no additional remarks) according to the progress.

Nonetheless, you can (and should) write about the topics in your thesis since it is your work you are describing. The only difference is that the statments you are making are not peer-reviewed, yet.

In general, it is a good idea to ask your supervisor about it since some can have different opinions on this topic.